# how to create three image view horizontally

Tags: android

how do i align three imageview horizontally like this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay5cy.jpg  how to make this typelayout. it is linearlayout or Relativelayout help me???
How can I make vertical combination of imageview and textview horizontally...?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:background="#F9F939"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_toLeftOf ="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="15dp" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#54F71D"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1DF7AB"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:padding="15dp" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I thing code is working fine with align horizontal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do like this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHome2Imag3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with orientation = horizontal

Answer (score -1):

use the property of android:layout_toLeftOf="+@id/img1" or android:layout_toRightOf="+@id/img1" if you want to use Relative layout. Otherwise its alright to go with the LinearLayout.